# Is this a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a section of code in my codebase that does the following:

```
function MyMethod(data: Data): void {
    const self = this;
    self.anotherMethod(data);
    ...
}
```

I'm all for typing my variables and was wondering if it were possible to type `self`.

If I type, `typeof(this)` in the Console DevTools, I get `object`. Doing the following:

`const self: object = this` results in an error,

> Property 'anotherMethod' does not exist on type 'object'.

Can I instead do something like `const self: this = this` ? The compiler doesn't seem to mind and I am able to call my method.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the question? If `self` was type `object`, then the compiler would know that `anotherMethod` does not exist on that type, even though it may exist at runtime. The point of declaring these types is to allow the compiler to assist based on the type information you give it.

Comment: Where is this function defined?

Comment: `typeof(this)` is only telling you JS runtime type, which is limited to a few primitives and the catch-all `object`, it doesn't tell you the TS type. Also `var self = this` will infer the type of `self` to be the same as `this`, so you don't need to give it a type annotation.